# JTable filter - replace foreign characters

Tags: java, swing, replace, jtable, rowfilter

this code below works for filtering JTable until I use english alphabet. It is also not case-sensitive. My goal is to filter white spaces and foreign characters. I need to replace characters in needle and in haystack somehow, for example č,ľ,ť,ž,ý,á replace with c,l,t,z,y,a.
Does anybody have experience or working code for my request? Thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  DefaultTableModel model;
  TableRowSorter sorter;

  public Home() {
    initComponents();
    model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    String data[] = {"šing","čamg","búng","wámg","fáng","raňk","moňk","púťk","šank","dung","puck","rig","an da da","ku nd ada","c ic inada"};
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      model.addRow(new Object[] {
        data[i]
      });
    }
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
  }

  private void initComponents() {///}                        

  private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        

    String text = jTextField1.getText();
    if(text.length() == 0) {
      sorter.setRowFilter(null);
    } else {
      sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
    }
  }                                       

  public static void main(String args[]) {///}

  // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
  private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
  // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: did you read offical Oracle tutorial How to use Tables - Filtering and Sorting, for working code example, didin't you ...

Comment: I read more than tutorial. Unfortunately, my Java level is very low and I didn't find out solution in tutorial for my problem.

Comment: (I read more than tutorial.) working code example uses DocumentListener for JTextField instread of (your wrong decision, never to use for JTextComponents) KeyListener, start there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mKorbel pointed out:

- Don't use `KeyListener` (bad approach) but [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead to
  listen for text field's text changes.
- The [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) still contains the text with foreign characters, so you
  should take this fact into account when you apply your filter.

Having said that, this is what I'd do:

- Have a method to apply a filter on your table based on a string.
- Attach a DocumentListener to the text field in order to call that method.
- Use `Normalizer`, as already suggested, in order to attach a row filter to the table's row sorter that takes into account both the original entry text value and its normalized string representation.

#### Example

Here's an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to play with.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * @author dic19
 */
public class Demo {

    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField;

    private void createAndShowGui() {

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
                Demo.this.filterTable(textField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
                Demo.this.filterTable(textField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
                Demo.this.filterTable(textField.getText());
            }
        });

        String[] header = new String[] {"Foreign text", "English text"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(header, 0) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return String.class;
            }
        };

        model.addRow(new Object[]{"šing", "wamg"});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"čamg", "bung"});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"búng", "sing"});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"wámg", "camg"});

        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
        filterPanel.add(new JLabel("Filter text:"));
        filterPanel.add(textField);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        content.add(filterPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        content.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void filterTable(final String query) {

        RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = null;

        if (query.length() > 0) {
            filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {

                    // Normalize the query string.
                    String normalizedQuery = Normalizer.normalize(query, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
                    normalizedQuery = normalizedQuery.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");

                    for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValueCount(); i++) {
                       // Get both the string value and its normalized string
                       String stringValue = entry.getStringValue(i);
                       String normalizedStringValue = Normalizer.normalize(stringValue, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
                       normalizedStringValue = normalizedStringValue.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");

                       // Two cases need to be evaluated here:
                       // 1. The normalized string value contains the normalized query string.
                       // 2. The string value contains the query string.
                       if (normalizedStringValue.contains(normalizedQuery) || stringValue.contains(query)) {
                           return true;
                       }
                   }
                   return false;
                }

            };
        }
        ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(filter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have imagined. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [java.text.Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html)

For example :

```
  String plain = "č,ľ,ť,ž,ý,á";
  plain = Normalizer.normalize(plain, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
  String clean = plain.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
  System.out.println(clean);
  // Will output c,l,t,z,y,a
```

The first steps replace the character:

```
U+010D LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON
```

By its "decomposed form":

```
U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C
U+030C COMBINING CARON
```

The second step delete all non ascii characters.

Comment: I know how to use this for needle (string from JTextField). But how can I apply this on haystack (strings from JTable)?

Comment: but in model are stored chars in form "č,ľ,ť,ž,ý,á", there is not the way

Comment: 1+ for Normalizer use and cleaning the non-ASCII characters. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I apply this to strings from `JTable`?

Apply the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27602793/230513) in a custom `TableCellRenderer`, as discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).